# Is there any way to translate @InvocableMethod label and description

Tags: invocable-method, translation

My company is providing a managed package that needs to be translated to many languages.

We managed to customise most labels using a CustomLabel metadata file. This is working fine for both lightning components and Apex code.

But I'm currently stuck with @InvocableMethod/@InvocableVariable labels:

```
@InvocableVariable(label='To Translate' description='Please translate me.')
```

What I tried so far with no success (gives me an error when compiling code):

```
//Use System.Label
@InvocableVariable(label=System.Label.my_label description=System.Label.my_desc)

//Use extra variable
String my_label = System.Label.my_label;
String my_desc = System.Label.my_desc;
@InvocableVariable(label=my_label description=my_desc)
```

Since those labels are going to appear on the user interface, I really need them to be translated. What's the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: I believe it is not possible at this time.